# IdentityServer4 and client with dynamic subdomain

Tags: identityserver4

I have setup Identity server 4 for our Angular application that will interact with a WebAPI
Identityserver is supposed to be used with Hybrid flow to get the token.
I have following issue -
My Angular application is defined in a way that it supports multiple tenant with subdomain like
tenant1.abc.com
tenant2.abc.com

Now as the angular application is the same and serving the multiple tenants, How can I defined client on Identityserver as it has subdomain and Identityserver will not be able to match the Client RedirectUris
and PostLogoutURI

Answer (score 0):

RedirectUI and PosrRedirectUri are checked for the Domain instead of Sub domain in code, while the sub Domain is validated by Tenant Table for Existance.